# php unique multidimensional array by keeping entry with the highes value from one dimension?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, unique, multidimensional-array

I have another array unique question in the endless list of questions about them.
I can imagine this problem is quite simple to solve but I simply do not come on it.
Just because there are so many questions on this subject i wasn't able to find anything useful in this case.

the array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => blabla values
      [1] => 91.181818181818
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
      [0] => blabla same values
      [1] => 95.333333333333
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
      [0] => blabla other values
      [1] => 86
    )
  [3] => Array
    (
      [0] => blabla other values
      [1] => 92.5
    )
  [4] => Array
    (
      [0] => blabla same values
      [1] => 88.5
    )
)
```

I want to unique the array by the first array dimension and only keep the entry with the highest value from the second.

Maybe in MYSQL this would be no big deal but at the moment i am not able to implement something like that in php.

desired output array would be:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => blabla values
      [1] => 91.181818181818
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
      [0] => blabla same values
      [1] => 95.333333333333
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
      [0] => blabla other values
      [1] => 92.5
    )
)
```

Has anyone a clever idea?

Comment: Thank you for your tick. Next time, you can use `var_export` to output `array`, then we will save a lot of time to type `91.181818181818`, :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$list = array(
    array('blabla values',91.181818181818),
    array('blabla same values', 95.333333333333),
    array('blabla other values', 86),
    array('blabla other values', 92),
    array('blabla same values', 88.5),
);
$result = array();
foreach ($list as $item)
{
    $key = $item[0];
    $value = $item[1];
    if (!isset($result[$key]) || $result[$key][1] < $value)
    {
        $result[$key] = $item;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => blabla values
            [1] => 91.1818181818
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => blabla same values
            [1] => 95.3333333333
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => blabla other values
            [1] => 92
        )

)
```

Comment: totally clear an logically, many thanks, exactly what im looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Hope that would be help. Any other questions, feel free to comment here.

Comment: But why don't you pick my answer?

Comment: Your algorithm seems to be the faster. so you get the tick. :)

Comment: @srain any way you could add comments to your work here? I am a bit of a noob and would like to understand this better. Thanks a bunch! (I will still probably use it if you don't, just won't know what the heck I am doing:P)

Comment: @ambe5960 Iterate the array. For each item, there are a key and a value. Use the key to store the item in `$result`. Once a greater value found, replace the whole item.

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b){
    return $a[1] - $b[1];
});
$out = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $out[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}
$arr = array_map(NULL, array_keys($out), $out);
```

Output:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => blabla same values
            [1] => 95.333333333333
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => blabla other values
            [1] => 86
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => blabla values
            [1] => 91.181818181818
        )

)
```

Comment: because of the "98.181818181818" i know you are writing a while, who now gains the tick? :D